# Allow specific IPv6 user to SSH into your server

Tags: networking, server, ssh, sftp, sshd

I have these settings in one of my servers.

```
Port 923
PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
X11Forwarding yes
PrintMotd no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
AllowUsers root code
Match Address 75.67.232.42
ListenAddress ::
```

I used to whitelist my home IP: 75.67.232.42 and it works

But now it updated to IPv6. I got locked out of my server but still have access via the provider.

How do I fix that? I've tried adding `ListenAddress::`

Comment: Try the IPv6 address on your `Match Address` line. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658184 for a similar problem and the correct syntax to solve it.

Comment: I tried it after the comma, and it is not working. I even restart the ssh too

Comment: Do I need do somthing else after that ?

Comment: Yeah I did as I mentioned.